# Travis CI AttributeError: object has no attribute 'assertCountEqual'

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, travis-ci

I'm facing an issue in a remote build environment while using `assertCountEqual` from python's built-in `unittest` module.

[This build](https://travis-ci.org/github/saurabmish/Data-Structures/builds/742548817) in Travis-CI throws this error while executing `coverage run -m unittest discover -v`.

However, I'm able to execute the command on my local environment - Python 3.8.5 Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried removing the `keys` dictionary attribute from the test data, but even then the [build failed](https://travis-ci.org/github/saurabmish/Data-Structures/builds/742582138) on the remote environment and executed on my local environment.

`test_bfs.py` and `test_dfs.py` are the files on which the build fails, and this is [repository](https://github.com/saurabmish/Data-Structures/tree/master/tests/unit).

This is the output on my local environment:

```
test_loop (tests.unit.test_bfs.TestBreadthFirstSearch)
Ensure no vertex points to itself. ... ok
test_number_of_vertices (tests.unit.test_bfs.TestBreadthFirstSearch)
Ensure that number of vertices is greater than 2. ... ok
test_valid_path_exists (tests.unit.test_bfs.TestBreadthFirstSearch)
Ensure a valid path exists for valid data, irrespective of order. ... ok
test_valid_path_not_none (tests.unit.test_bfs.TestBreadthFirstSearch)
Ensure valid path is returned for valid data. ... ok
test_loop (tests.unit.test_dfs.TestDepthFirstSearch)
Ensure no vertex points to itself. ... ok
test_number_of_vertices (tests.unit.test_dfs.TestDepthFirstSearch)
Ensure that number of vertices is greater than 2. ... ok
test_valid_path_exists (tests.unit.test_dfs.TestDepthFirstSearch)
Ensure a valid path exists for valid data, irrespective of order. ... ok
test_valid_path_not_none (tests.unit.test_dfs.TestDepthFirstSearch)
Ensure valid path is returned for valid data. ... ok
test_sequence (tests.unit.test_inorder_traversal.TestInOrderTraversal)
Compare expected output with tree structure. ... ok
test_common_ancestor (tests.unit.test_lowest_common_ancestor.TestLowestCommonAncestor)
Check whether node 2 is the ancestor of node 1. ... ok
test_different_branch_ancestor (tests.unit.test_lowest_common_ancestor.TestLowestCommonAncestor)
Verify ancestor when both nodes belong to different subtrees. ... ok
test_same_branch_ancestor (tests.unit.test_lowest_common_ancestor.TestLowestCommonAncestor)
Verify ancestor when both nodes belong to the same subtree. ... ok
test_sequence (tests.unit.test_postorder_traversal.TestPostOrderTraversal)
Compare expected output with tree structure. ... ok
test_sequence (tests.unit.test_preorder_traversal.TestPreOrderTraversal)
Compare expected output with tree structure. ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 14 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Can someone please let me know how I can fix this error on Travis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a hint from the pip output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.

  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
```

this is actually running python2.7 where `assertCountEqual` does not exist

I'd suggest using `python -m pip ...` to install things -- this will make sure you're using the version of python you expect

Comment: But before executing test cases, there is `python --version`, which outputs `Python 3.8.0`. Should this not be enough?

Comment: `python` and `pip` are not the same executable so they could come from different installations

Comment: Thank you Anthony! I'm waiting for the build to finish.

Comment: :) I have a directory called `queue` (and there's a class `Queue` in it as well) in the project root, which I think may be causing the issue. I saw this here https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/298  I'll look at both aspects and will then confirm.